# C++ Итерация по контейнеру. Многопоточность

Tags: c++, многопоточность, списки

Существует некий контейнер, содержит числа, пускай это будет от 0 до 10. В системе есть 2 потока:

1. Бегает в форе по итератору
2. Случайно удаляет элемент массива

Вопрос в следующем, получается что если в момент удаления потоком #2, элемента допустим под номером 4, а поток #1 находится на итерации на номере 2 и двигается в сторону удаленного номера 4, то получается что приложение падает? Интересует как такую ситуацию можно разрешить

Comment: Уточните какой контейнер используется. А то можно написать такой контейнер, который вполне будет работать с двумя потоками без проблем.

Comment: Используется обычный std::list

Answer (score 8):

Без изменений в структуре данных никак.

Стандартные контейнеры C++ непотокобезопасны, это раз. Даже если вы сделаете их потокобезопасными, окружив их использование мьютексом, любая операция с контейнером в одном потоке инвалидирует итераторы в другом потоке, и доступ по ним приводит к UB и в лучшем случае крешу (а в худшем — к расстрелу памяти).

Вам придётся держать дополнительные данные. Например, в .NET принят такой подход: когда коллекция меняется, увеличивается *номер версии* данных. Читающий поток, получив мьютекс, может проверить, не изменился ли номер версии данных, и при изменении выкинуть свои итераторы и начать обход коллекции по-новой.

Впрочем, если вы обходите коллекцию *быстро*, можно пойти на более простое решение: блокировать всю коллекцию на время обхода.

Comment: А как же libcds?

Comment: @PinkTux: А что это? Если это помогает, пишите ответ. Мой ответ про стандартный C++.

Comment: перемкнуло немного, решил, что [оно](http://libcds.sourceforge.net/) чуть ли не в стандарте уже :) Вот тут подробней: https://habrahabr.ru/post/195770/

Comment: @PinkTux, но к стандартным итераторам это не имеет отношения.

Comment: @avp, да, сглючил. Но, справедливости ради, о *стандартных* в вопросе не говорилось, только о *неких* :-)

Comment: @VladD контейнеры бывают разные. Для map, например, при удалении испортится только итератор того, что удаляется. Значит, трюк с мьютексом для него пройдет.

Comment: @gbg: Не вполне понимаю: а если у нас на руках итератор на удаляемый элемент, как мы определим этот случай?

Comment: @PinkTux: Ого, круто. А они проблему ABA решили?

Comment: @VladD сажать мьютекс во все элементы. Это позволит не грохнуть захваченный конкурентом элемент.

Comment: @gbg: Хм, а можно код? Не представляю себе, как это должно выглядеть.

Comment: @VladD ближе к вечеру по МСК, не раньше.

Comment: @VladD, ABA оно же не решается кроме как на железячном уровне?

Comment: @PinkTux: Возможно, тем же версионированием? Не уверен.

Comment: @VladD - я выложил код в виде ответа

Answer (score 2):

Пример функций-кокурентов для std::map;

Стандарт [гарантирует для map](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15067564/5533854), что при константном доступе на чтение, все проблемы могут случиться, только если ломать тот самый итератор, который другой поток в это время обрабатывает.

Поэтому, мы обвешаем итератор мьютексом, и будем внимательно следить, чтобы наездов не было.

```
using testmap=std::map<string, uint8_t>;

struct Context
{
    mutex lock;
    testmap::const_iterator location;
};

void print_data(ostream& str,const testmap& data,Context& context)
{
    {
        lock_guard<mutex> g(context.lock);

        context.location=begin(data);
    }
    while(true)
    {
        str << context.location->first << ' ' << context.location->second << endl;

        {
            lock_guard<mutex> g(context.lock);

            ++context.location;
            if(context.location==end(data))
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

void kill_data(testmap& data,Context& context)
{

    std::default_random_engine generator;
    while(auto l=data.size())
    {
        std::uniform_int_distribution<decltype(l)> distr(0,l);

        const auto pos=distr(generator);

        auto el=begin(data);

        for(size_t i=0;i!=pos;++i)
        {
            ++el;
        }

        {
            lock_guard<mutex> g(context.lock);

            if(context.location!=el)
            {
                data.erase(el);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @VladD Потому, что удалятор точно удаляет какой-то другой элемент, не тот, который мы выводим.  if(context.location!=el) же

Comment: Ага, понял. То есть у вас в контексте блокировка на _весь_ контейнер, и один запрещённый к удалению итератор. То есть по идее если у вас будет N читателей, то нужен будет список итераторов в контексте?

Comment: @VladD - точно так, да.